# GraphQL conditional required field directive

Tags: graphql

Most of my input validation is available at the GraphQL layer. I would like to enhance it by making certain fields required if other fields have specific values. I think it might be possible to do that using custom directives, but after a bit of dabbling I am still not sure. **Is it possible to access the value of a sibling field in a field directive?**

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell if this fits your particular scenario without more context but hopefully this helps:

Your directive will have something like this:

```
export class MyDirective extends SchemaDirectiveVisitor {
  visitFieldDefinition(field) {
    const { resolve = defaultFieldResolver } = field;
    const directiveArgs = { ...this.args };
    field.resolve = async function(obj, args, context, info) {
    ...
```

from there you can retrieve the value of other fields on this type by accessing obj.

e.g. for a schema that has:

```
type MyType {
  foo: String
  bar: String @MyDirective
}
```

you could throw an error resolving bar in the directive by doing:

```
export class MyDirective extends SchemaDirectiveVisitor {
  visitFieldDefinition(field) {
    const { resolve = defaultFieldResolver } = field;
    const directiveArgs = { ...this.args };
    field.resolve = async function(obj, args, context, info) {
    let result = resolve.call(this, result, args, context, info);
    if (obj.foo === "something" && result === null) throw new Error("Some error");
    return result
```

Comment: This is for return types. I'd like validation for input types : ]